# SIngle digit sum of digit of a number large case fail

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, while-loop

I am trying a problem in which we are supposed to calculate the sum of digits of a number recursively until there is a single digit left.My program fails for 2 very specific test cases(10^15) digits.The logic is working for smaller inputs(<10^15).

Here is my code

```
import sys
test_cases=int(input())

number_single=list(range(0,10))

while(test_cases!=0):
    digit_sum=0
    summation1=0
    summation2=0
    sub_case=int(input())

    while(sub_case!=0):
        length,number=map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
        summation=length*number
        summation1+=summation

        sub_case=sub_case-1
        digit_sum,digit_sum1=summation1,summation1



            while(digit_sum not in number_single):
             digit1_sum=digit_sum%10
             digit_sum=int(digit_sum/10)
             digit_sum=digit1_sum+digit_sum

             print(digit_sum)
    test_cases=test_cases-1
```

Desired output is of the form say if the number is 17654 then the output is 5.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, all pertinent information must be included in the posting.  As it is, all four of your links are invalid (access denied).

Comment: First of all, your code doesn't run; the indentation is incorrect.  Given the lack of clean logic, we can't really tell what you intended.  For instance, you have three input commands when it would seem that only one is warranted.  Perhaps you enter the quantity of inputs, then the inputs themselves, as needed?

Comment: Why do you have two summation loops for only a single process?

Comment: I tried to fix your indentation, but I still fail to follow the program logic.  You first require the quantity of inputs, then the inputs (one at a time), and then, at each sub_case iteration, you require yet more input.

Comment: By the way, you state that your two failing cases have 10^15 digits.  Are you *really* testing this on a terabyte of input?!

Comment: Finally, this appears to be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106989/digital-sum-python).  I'd tag the question, but I've already voted to close for another reason.

Comment: The input is of the form of length and digits i.e a digit appears length no of times.For each iteration,i am calculating the sum til my sub iterations(sub_case0 is not equal to zero.It is a problem from hackerearth.And the links are time based i guess,so i can't add them.Maybe can i add text files for the input and output?

Comment: You can simply paste the input and output as text (not file links), and format them as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of other understanding, I'll provide some basic code that may help you clear out some of your extra design.

First of all, this is called the "digital root" of the number.  The old term for the process is "casting out nines".  It's trivial to do with the modulus operator:

```
target = 314159265358979323846364338327950197169

dig_root = target % 9
if dig_root == 0:
    dig_root = 9
print ("digital root", dig_root)
```

However, if you're supposed to work through the "manual" process of adding digits, then take advantage of the language's type capabilities.  Convert it to string, convert each character to a single-digit integer, and add them.  Repeat until the sum is no more than 9.

```
while target > 9:
    target_str = str(target)
    target = 0
    for c in target_str:
        target += int(c)
print (target)
```

Using a list comprehension, this reduces to

```
while target > 9:
    target = sum([int(c) for c in str(target)])
    print (target)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.The test case was not getting passed because i was not using floor division(//) and instead i was performing normal division and taking the integer result.This was causing the program to fail for those 2 large cases.